# Function.prototype does not show all in-built properties and methods in console

Tags: javascript, browser, javascript-objects

This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) on `Function.prototype` objects lists native properties and methods however when I echo `Function.prototype` in Firefox or Chrome's console, it outputs `"function () { }"`.

Why does not it output all the properties and methods as listed on MDN article?

Comment: Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply how the browser decides to "show" you the object, because reasons.

In Chrome you can do `dir(Function.prototype)` and it will list all methods and properties of the object. Firefox may have something similar.

UPDATE: In Firefox you can simply right click on what it shows you when you do `Function.prototype` and select "Open in variables view" where it will list you all properties and methods.

Comment: Just left-clicking should also work on Firefox. But due to a bug it opens an empty tab.